# What can I do to avoid memory leaks in my Android app?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

My android app is taking more and more memory over time. I took a heap dump and analyzed it with MAT.

Here's the main leak suspect :[image]

So it seems like one of my activities isn't cleared from memory after I quit the app (with back button) then when I restart the app a new instance is created and fills in the memory.

Now if they're PhantomReferences why the memory isn't cleared after a while or when I quit the app? The memory is never cleared even when I use other app etc. The only way to completely close the app is to use a task manager to manually kill the app.

What can I do to avoid this anarchic memory consumption ?

EDIT:

I found the problem!
Each activity was setting up a CustomExceptionHandler with Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() and that CustomExceptionHandler was keeping a reference to the context. So I got rid of the context reference and I 'nulled' the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in the onDestroy() method. That's really better now!

Comment: Do you have Thread, Asyntasks... ?

Comment: +1 for anarchic memory usage!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the dominator tree functionality of MAT to find out what is above those references, this may give you an idea of which `Activity` is the culprit.

Make sure you haven't passed a `Context` anywhere and held a reference to it, this is a classic android memory leak and it's really easy to do!

Although some static analysis tools frown on this, in the `onDestroy()` methods of your `Activity` you can `null` all your local variables (except primitives), it helps to nudge the garbage collector sometimes and can make for an easier to analyse heap dump in MAT.

Comment: I guess local variables are taken off the stack automatically when the method exits. Do you mean the instance variables should be marked as null in onDestroy() method? I am a bit unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Some generic approaches to reduce size of the app what I generally follow is this :

- Call finish() below passing an Intent to next activity, this will avoid piling up of stack and helps in gc(garbage collection)
- If you are not using shared preferences to save data, flush them at exit by calling System.exit()
- If you find any drawable images/layout xmls/java classes which you are not using in your final program, ensure you remove them from the project
- Images have to be .png since JPEG images take lot of memory.
- In case of using database(sqlite, internal database etc), a better approach would be using "try/catch/finally" blocks, In try you open the db, in finally you close it, which will avoid memory leaks caused because of not closing cursors or databases.
- Use AsyncTask instead of threads. in onPostExecute()function, close the progress dialogs if any.